# I'm not able to open Configuration Manager for SQL Server 2008 R2 on windows 10 64- bit

Tags: sql-server

There is no Configuration Manager in my apps in the start menu. I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on windows 10 64bit but unfortunately i'm not able to find the Configuration Manager App. I need it to use to change the server name of my SQL Server which was localhost before.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMXYU.png)

C:\Windows\system32\SQLServerManager10.msc
By using this link still it is showing the app but it's not opening

By using this SQLSERVERMANAGER10.msc on run command window. The following picture elaborates[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMhii.png) the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the server is effectively running? The is the most common cause.

Launch Administrative Tools\Services and look for SQLSERVER

Also make sure the SQLSERVER Browser process is also running to enable connection discovery by client applications.

Comment: Maybe this is what happened to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013